# TSQL query for Python Flask project

Tags: python, sql

[Table[image]s]

I am trying to get a project done for school Monday.  I have 2 tables (users and books) that have a many-to-many relationship with a joiner table I called favorites.  I am displaying the book titles in a web page (python/flask/jinja) and have a query that works to display all book titles, but the problem is that beneath each book I have to add a link to (add to favorites) if that particular book has not been liked by the current logged in user.

I need this to be one query to display in the same div.

My tables are linked in the image link above.

my select query

```
select *  from users  join favorites on users.id = favorites.user_id  join books on books.id = favorites.book_id
```

The problem I have is when I have a book that is liked by the current user and another user.  How do I filter out the book that is liked by non-logged in users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query selects the relations between all users and their books. You should use the 'WHERE' clause if you want to find only the books liked by current user:

```
select *  from users 
join favorites on users.id = favorites.user_id 
join books on books.id = favorites.book_id 
where users.id = current_user_id
```

EDIT:

If you want to display all books and also shows which ones a particular user liked:

```
select b.*,u.* from books as b
left join favorites as f on f.book_id = b.id
left join users as u on u.id = f.user_id and u.id = current_user_id
group by b.id
```

If the current user doesn't have the book as a favorite, the users columns will be null.

You can also create a column representing the favorite status:

```
select b.*,u.*,IF(u.id is null,0,1) as favorited
from books as b
left join favorites as f on f.book_id = b.id
left join users as u on u.id = f.user_id and u.id = current_user_id
group by b.id
```

Comment: yes, I understand the WHERE clause, but the problem is that I am displaying the results in a webpage using python/flask.  I need to use one query to display all the books and then underneath each book a link to favorite that book if the user has not already favorited that book.  Therefore, I need to get all books and then somehow narrow out when several people have favorited that book along with the Current logged in user.  sorry, does that make sense?

Comment: That did the trick, Victor!  Thank you very much for you help!  I appreciate it!

Comment: No problem! If the answer worked for you, [please accept it as a valid answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). "*To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in"*

Comment: Thanks. I just did.